# Wordpress, how restrict what categories a post can be assigned to?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have three Platforms, so I want 3 'add-new-post' pages.

-add to IOS 
-add to Android 
-add to Web

So when you create a new post I want this:

[image: assign to category]

To limit the selection to the LOWEST level of the respective parent categories: IOS - Android - Web. So a function with a 'depth' option is preferred...

Also the website is already built and content is rendered based on category hierarchy so tags aren't a option. This is an an attempt to improve accessibility.

Comment: I don't see how that could possibly improve accessibility. I would suggest instead you use javascript to collapse and expand the subcategories. This would help you reduce the noise for your users.